# ESLint + Airbnb without eslint-plugin-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to use ESLint + Airbnb and I'm receiving the error message:

> Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'

But I'm not using `eslint-plugin-react` see above my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  rules: {
    'no-console': 0,
    'linebreak-style': [2, 'windows'],
    'no-new': 0,
    'eslint eol-last': ['error', 'never'],
  },
};
```

But unfortunately I'm receiving the error message before mentioned. I have no idea about the error. I'm not using `eslint-plugin-react`. Tell me why this plugin its required

Comment: are you trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, and I found out that there was a global `.eslintrc` which included react!

[image]

This is possibly because I had ESLint installed globally before and/or some generator tool created that global config. Although you're running ESLint locally now, it always looks for global configuration.
Of course, deleting the global config resolved the problem.
It's in your user directory (e.g.: `C:\Users\<username>`)
**Be careful and check whether any other projects depend on the global config**.

Comment: Also I noticed that it might search for a .eslintrc in any ancestor directory in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

According to [their thread on git](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/451), add `{ "extends": "airbnb/base" }` to your config.

edit: the above is deprecated. The same thread recommends to use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base